# Hibernate criteria with Distinct and order by

Tags: java, hibernate

can anyone tell me how to use hibernate criteria with Distinct and order by. i've been looking for a solution but can't seem to find one

thanks.

Comment: Could you describe the specific problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following?
            criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

Reference: http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/examples/criteria/hibernate-distinct-criteria.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the code is Used to retrieve the data of a city.

```
 List<City> entityList = (List<City>)session.createCriteria(className)
                                            .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
.add(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("state"))))
.addOrder(Order.asc("state"))                                           .add(criterion).list();
```